# Question about the existence of non-piecewise functions - trivial or impossible?

Tags: real-analysis

I've been working on a problem about functions and I simply can't figure out what the answer is. I'm not sure at all how trivial or complicated this problem is in the scope of mathematics - or even how widely known it is in real analysis already - but I'll appreciate your suggestions. I'll present both the weaker and the stronger versions of the problem. Thanks for your help in advance.

$\\$

**Problem (weaker version)**

Let $b_1 , b_2 , ...,b_n$ be any posivite integers. Does there always exist real numbers $a_1 < a_2 < ...<a_n$ and a non-piecewise function $f(x)$ such that $f(a_1)=b_1, f(a_2)=b_2,..., f(a_n)=b_n$ for every $n$ ?

$\\$

**Problem (stronger version)**

Let $a_1 , a_2 , ...,a_n$ and $b_1 , b_2 , ...,b_n$ be any real numbers where $ a_1 < a_2 < ...<a_n$. Does there always exist a non-piecewise function $f(x)$ such that $f(a_1)=b_1, f(a_2)=b_2,..., f(a_n)=b_n$ for every $n$ ?

$\\$

**Note:** By "non-piecewise" function, I'm refering to a function $f(x)$ that doesn't require to be defined in terms of two or more sub-functions, where each sub-function applies to a different interval (or single points) in the domain. Under this definition, $f(x)$ = $|x|$ is an example of a piecewise function whilst $f(x)$ = cos$(|x|)$ and $f(x) = x^2$ are examples of non-piecewise functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition

Comment: So if I define $\lvert x\rvert$ as $\sqrt{x^2}$ you suddenly start liking it? If I define $\lfloor x\rfloor=\max\{n\in\Bbb Z\,:\, n\le x\}$, is this function piecewise or not?

Comment: "Piecewise" isn't really a well-defined property of functions, since at their core, functions do not carry any information about how they were defined. A function is its graph (plus some minor additional information), which is essentially just a table containing all its values in the form of tuples $(x,f(x))$. There's nothing in there that could allow you to deduce wether it was defined piecewise or not. Was $f:x\mapsto\vert x\vert$ defined piecewise or as $\sqrt{x^2}$? Don't know. All we know is that $f(-2)=2$. Why this equality holds is not something the function will ever tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem: Even Stronger Version**

Let $a_1 , a_2 , ...,a_n$ and $b_1 , b_2 , ...,b_n$ be any real numbers where $ a_1 < a_2 < ...<a_n$. Does there always exist a smooth $C^\infty$ function $f(x)$ such that $f(a_1)=b_1, f(a_2)=b_2,..., f(a_n)=b_n$ for every $n$?

Yes. One such function is the [Lagrange Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).